# toolbar with buttons on uitableviewcontroller [Monotouch if possible]

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I added image(background) with custom buttons at the very bottom of UITableViewController , but when I add more cells , my custom image and buttons doesn't stay at the very bottom where it suppose to stay , it floats up as i scroll down. I tried to add it as TableFooterView but it would show at the end of the cells...Now, is it possible to have it fixed at the footer of the view without it moving up and down...Please look at the pic below 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a `UITableViewController` why not use a `UIViewController` and add a `UITableView` to it, together with your custom toolbar beneath the table view. This will ensure that the table view scrolling does not affect your toolbar position.

Comment: ok ,let's say i did that , do u think i need to change implementation of the UITableViewController ??

Comment: no - use a UIViewController instead, setting it as the datasource and delegate

Comment: Alright,i added UIViewController as parent , add put the TableView as child and set it's class to UITableView and made outlet.All worked good but the upper custom bar and bottom bar are still floating up and down .

Comment: Ok , the ultimate goal is to add UIView(image + buttons) at the top and bottom and make them stay , just like when regular ToolBar behavior ...how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding the ViewDidLoad method in the UITableViewController and change the TableView's Frame.

Comment: I tried that but didn't have any effect on the TableView's Frame